# Even though my HTMLCollection has 10 elements, slides[0] returns undefined?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the display style property of `slides[0]` to block using:

```
let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
slides[0].style.display = "block";
```

However, `slides[0]` seems to be undefined even though `console.log(slides)` returns a `HTMLCollection` with 10 divs in it.

I'm not sure if this matters, but the function that uses this code exists in the `mounted()` lifecycle hook of Vue.js. I executed the same code inside an HTML file where the JavaScript was in the  tag and it worked fine.

Comment: Pretty sure you just asked this same question a bit ago - if the linked canonicals aren't sufficient, please edit a [MCVE] into the question so that the problem can be reproduced, so as to make the question answerable

Comment: [You just asked this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55680851/10221765)